# unable to edit cell in ag-grid-react grid when populating from graphql

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-react

using ag-grid with react andtypescript, I have a column defined as editible which is initialised with data (held in state) from a GraphQL query.

When editing the cell I get the following error:
**TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'destination' of object '#'**

The code it falls over in is
    ValueService../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/valueService/valueService.js.ValueService.setValue

[image]

Does anyone know where it is trying to store the changed values and why this occurs?

Snippets of code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    // we use state because the columns might change dynamically
    this.setState( {   columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs() });
}
createColumnDefs() {
    return [
        { colId: 'b', headerName: 'ID', field: 'rowID', hide: true },
        { colId: 'c', headerName: 'Name No.', field: 'nameNo', hide: true },
        { colId: 'h', headerName: 'Destination', field: 'destination', editable: true},
        { colId: 'i', headerName: 'CopyTo', field: 'copyTo', editable: true },
        { colId: 'j', headerName: 'Subject', field: 'subject', editable: true },
        { colId: 'k', headerName: 'Body', field: 'body', editable: true }
    ];
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: SelectionQueryProps) {
    ........
    // props come from an Apollo/GraphQL wrapper so setting it in state
    this.setState( { data: nextProps.data } );
    }
}
render() {
    if (!this.state.data || this.state.data.loading || !this.state.data.statementCreation) {
        return <div><Loader active={true} inline="centered" size="large" /></div>;
    }
    return (
                    <AgGridReact
                        animateRows={true}
                        enableColResize={true}
                        enableFilter={true}
                        enableSorting={true}
                        enableRangeSelection={true}
                        rowModelType="inMemory"
                        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                        singleClickEdit={true}
                        stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus={true}
                        rowSelection={'multiple'}
                        onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
                        onRowSelected={this.onRowSelected}
                        suppressRowClickSelection={this.props.generate}
                    />
    );
}
private onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    if (this.state.data && !this.state.data.loading && this.state.data.statementCreation) {
        params.api.setRowData(this.state.data.statementCreation);
        params.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns('autosizeColumns');
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some of your actual code, I guess the problem might not with the ag-grid. Can you make a plunker?

Comment: Thanks. My  guess is that it isnt an ag-grid issue which is why i am trying to found out where the data is stored that the grid tried to modify.
I will try to recreate it in plunker but will post some code in case it is something obvious